# H20: how to use gradient boosting on textual data?

Tags: r, apache-spark, h2o, sparklyr, text2vec

I am trying to implement a very simple ML learning problem, where I use text to predict some outcome. In R, some basic example would be:

import some fake but funny text data

```
library(caret)
library(dplyr)
library(text2vec)

dataframe <- data_frame(id = c(1,2,3,4),
                        text = c("this is a this", "this is 
                        another",'hello','what???'),
                        value = c(200,400,120,300),
                        output = c('win', 'lose','win','lose'))

> dataframe
# A tibble: 4 x 4
     id            text value output
  <dbl>           <chr> <dbl>  <chr>
1     1  this is a this   200    win
2     2 this is another   400   lose
3     3           hello   120    win
4     4         what???   300   lose
```

Use `text2vec` to get a **sparse** matrix representation of my text (see also https://github.com/dselivanov/text2vec/blob/master/vignettes/text-vectorization.Rmd)

```
#these are text2vec functions to tokenize and lowercase the text
prep_fun = tolower
tok_fun = word_tokenizer 

#create the tokens
train_tokens = dataframe$text %>% 
  prep_fun %>% 
  tok_fun

it_train = itoken(train_tokens)     
vocab = create_vocabulary(it_train)
vectorizer = vocab_vectorizer(vocab)
dtm_train = create_dtm(it_train, vectorizer)

> dtm_train
4 x 6 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
  what hello another a is this
1    .     .       . 1  1    2
2    .     .       1 .  1    1
3    .     1       . .  .    .
4    1     .       . .  .    .
```

Finally, train the algo (for instance, using `caret`) to predict `output` using my sparse matrix.

```
mymodel <- train(x=dtm_train, y =dataframe$output, method="xgbTree")

> confusionMatrix(mymodel)
Bootstrapped (25 reps) Confusion Matrix 

(entries are percentual average cell counts across resamples)

          Reference
Prediction lose  win
      lose 17.6 44.1
      win  29.4  8.8

 Accuracy (average) : 0.264
```

**My problem is:**

I see how to import data into `h20` using `spark_read_csv`, `rsparkling`  and `as_h2o_frame`. 
However, for points 2. and 3. above I am completely lost.

Can someone please give me some hints or tell me if this approach is even possible with `h2o`?

Many thanks!!

Comment: What is the `it_train` variable?  I think you missed a step in your code (it's almost reproducible, but not yet).

Comment: hey @ErinLeDell you are right. hold on one sec

Comment: @ErinLeDell question updated!

Comment: Still missing `it_train`.  You added `train_tokens` instead?

Comment: LOL. you realize it has been a looong day. :D

Comment: question updated ... sorry!

Comment: Third time's a charm. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this one of two ways -- 1. in R first and then move to H2O for modeling or 2. Entirely in H2O using H2O's word2vec implementation.

Use R data.frames and **text2vec**, then convert the sparse matrix to an H2O frame and do the modeling in H2O.

```
 # Use same code as above to get to this point, then:

 # Convert dgCMatrix to H2OFrame, cbind the response col
 train <- as.h2o(dtm_train)
 train$y <- as.h2o(dataframe$output)

 # Train any H2O model (e.g GBM)
 mymodel <- h2o.gbm(y = "y", training_frame = train,
                   distribution = "bernoulli", seed = 1)
```

Or you can train a word2vec embedding in H2O, apply it to your text to get the equivalent of a sparse matrix.  Then train a H2O machine learning model 
 (GBM).  I will try edit this answer later with a working example using your data, but in the meantime, here is an [example](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-r/demos/rdemo.word2vec.craigslistjobtitles.R) demonstrating the use of H2O's word2vec functionality in R.

Comment: that's really cool, @ErinLeDell. Looking forward to your working example! Thanks

Comment: But where did you find something about word2vec in question? Text2vec != Word2vec. Question is about how to export sparse matrix to h2o! And the way to do it - convert matrix to svmlight format.

Comment: The task Noobie asked about was the H2O-only equivalent of training a model on text -- I mean you can perform the same task (using Word2Vec) in H2O.  The solution above allows you to keep using text2vec, but it also requires performing the text-processing computation in R memory (rather than distributed H2O w2v), so I suggested H2O w2v as a work-around.

Comment: @DmitriySelivanov exactly. In R, I stick to your nice package. In Spark, I hope the great ErinLeDell will be able to show a 100% H2o example using my small toy model :D Thanks to both you guys

Comment: @erin-ledell still it is different. h2o allows to obtains vectors for words or for sentences (averaged word vectors). But example here was about bag-of-words model and large sparse matrix. BTW I took a look on how h2o coerces sparse matrix to the internal format (https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-r/h2o-package/R/frame.R#L3219-L3251) - it is nightmare. I will send PR.

Comment: @DmitriySelivanov I am being the promoter of increasing synergies between `text2vec` and `h2o`! Dmitry what do you mean it is nightmare? That would not work with large sparce matrices?

Comment: 1) it is just wrong - silently and implicitly considers first column as target variable 2) will work very (very) long even for small data sets

Comment: @DmitriySelivanov were you able to change the code in h20 then?

Comment: @noobie, for example use https://github.com/dselivanov/sparsio to write matrix as svmlight. Then you can read it with `h2o.uploadFile`.

Comment: @DmitriySelivanov The code is not wrong. We use SVMLight to transfer sparse data, the first column of a SVMLight file is the target/response variable. The implication of using it for just a generic matrix-like structure is that the first column always has a dense representation, the rest of the matrix has sparse representation.

Comment: Of course it is. Even in example above first column is not target, but h2o converts it to  target and then override with actual target.

Comment: @DmitriySelivanov , Erin Le Dell please dont fight, cooperate! Just answer my original question! :D

Comment: @ErinLeDell accepting while hoping for a pure `h20` small example as well :D